# Search paths "/usr/local/include/glm/gtx" versus Use of undeclared identifier 'gtx'

Tags: c++, glm-math

Mac Big Sur C++ OpenGL attempting to learn quaternions from a tutorial.
The gtx headers are under `usr/local/include/glm`.
Can anyone figure out what is wrong with my header includes or header search path? Thanks.

Minimum reproducible code that fails for this issue:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdocumentation"
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> // for window and keyboard
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>
int main ( void )
{
    float t =1.0;
    // http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/
    glm::vec3 RotationAxis(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    float RotationAngle = 90 * t;
    glm::quat MyQuaternion;
    MyQuaternion = gtx::quaternion::angleAxis(glm::degrees(RotationAngle), RotationAxis);
    return 0;
}
```

The build error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'gtx'
```

which occurs on the line with `gtx`.

My Build Phases / Header Search Paths / Debug / Any Architecture:

```
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/include/glm
/usr/local/include/glm/gtx
/usr/local/Cellar
/glew/2.2.0_1/include/GL
/usr/local/Cellar
/glfw/3.3.4/include/GLFW
/usr/local/include/glad/include
```

My Library Search Paths:
$(inherited) /usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/lib /usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.4/lib /usr/local/include /usr/local/include/glad/include

Comment: Can you prove your compiler wrong? You have acknowledged the use of the identifier `gtx`, so the only point of contention is whether or not it is declared. Can you point to the lines where `gtx` is declared?

Comment: I'm not following. I understand that a variable and a function need to be declared, if they are to be defined later in the program, or same with a class, to be defined in a separate file. I am not sure what the meaning of "declare" is in the context of a header-only file. I do not have a particular "declare" for glm, but glm::vec3 does not raise an error. Can you expand on this?

Comment: @user3027106 Every identifier needs to be declared before it can be used. Sometimes a definition serves as the declaration. Sometimes the declaration is separate. But the declaration is always required. Where is the line that tells the compiler what `gtx` is the name of? (If it is a namespace, its declaration is probably a line like `namespace gtx` followed by an opening brace, the contents of the namespace, then a closing brace.)

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for fast responses.

user17732522 said the thing that appears to allow the code to build and run.

I don't know the protocol to get the credit to the right answerer.

Comment: @user3027106 I have added the information to my answer and undeleted it. If you feel that it was helpful you can accept it, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But note that I didn't check whether this really works and the functions still behave as the tutorial expects.

Comment: @user17732522 your answer qualifies as "most helpful". I will see, later, if the functions in that namespace work as advertised. But the code builds and runs, which was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tutorial 1 of the link in the comment, the author introduces

```
using namespace glm;
```

which I assume they expect you to use throughout the tutorials.

The namespace that you want to look into is not just `gtx`, but `glm::gtx`, so without the `using namespace` you need to fully qualify it:

```
MyQuaternion = glm::gtx::quaternion::angleAxis(glm::degrees(RotationAngle), RotationAxis);
```

---

However, the tutorial seems to be rather old. As far as I can tell, the entities it uses from the `glm::gtx::quaternion` namespace have been moved to the `glm` namespace many years ago, see [github commit](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/commit/3621deaeb581ebbf45ac38144497a5b337791fc3).

So, without knowing whether anything else changed about these functions, it seems you should replace `gtx::quaternion` with `glm` in the code from your question and the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for answering right away. I did that out of desperation and it didn't fix it. I can update the question so that that is reflected.
If I try that right now: "MyQuaternion = glm::gtx::quaternion::angleAxis(glm::degrees(RotationAngle), RotationAxis);" causes "No member named 'gtx' in namespace 'glm'"